# Exceeding max RPM of wind turbine

Tags: power, generator, output, energy, rpm

I have a wind turbine that reaches its max output power at 1000 RPM, and I want to know if there's any problem if I make it go faster than that (e.g. around 1250 RPM).

I have a TESUP Yuzo. You can find its manual [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AmqLDd2pksIFjmOSxopSq-LZ87-yd28R/view)

I will not be using the blades. Just the shaft.

Comment: what kind of turbine do you have?

Comment: Please provide a link to the product's manual or data sheet. Add the link to your question.

Comment: The only people who can answer this are the manufacturers. But be sure to explain your use case otherwise the answer will certainly be yes.

Comment: Max speed is Hurricane scale 2: 43–49 m/s   And chart goes to 15 m/s.  So shaft can go faster. *Microprocessor controlled charge with integrated voltage and current limiting.*  The controller will probably limit output current so power is 200W to protect internal wiring.

Comment: @Andyaka The language in your deleted comment is absolutely unacceptable. You will not do it again.

Comment: @Null was it my decision not use a profanity but use it's initials that was the problem? I've thought about this and didn't think that abbreviation was unacceptable. I've seen it used quite a few times on this site. Of course, I'll not use it again.

Comment: @Andyaka Your comment was obviously unfriendly (which is against the [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct)), and the use of profanity -- even "only" initials only makes it worse. Even if you've seen it elsewhere on the site, that is not an excuse for you to use it. Instead, you should flag its use by other users. You know all this as you've been warned many times before. This is your last warning. Your language on this site had better be impeccable. If you have *any* doubt about your language I suggest you find a better way to put it.

Comment: It's easy to find a BLDC motor that will exceed your  specs and easily work at 1250RPM or higher. Look for one with a suitably low RPM/V and add a 3 phase rectifier. Given there are better solutions, and probably cheaper since you're not paying for bits you're not using, why bother pulling the generator out of a wind turbine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably shouldn't plan to exceed the maximum RPM as stated in the datasheet of 1000RPM. 
What will happen if you do is pretty much guesswork, but I would guess that you'd see a decreased lifetime. The Overspeed would likely cause excessive heating and cause the turbine to fail sooner, how much sooner depends on how much overspeed, how well-built the device is, and possibly other factors I don't know about.
You could also find that if the device generates more power than it is designed to, this causes extra heating in the wiring/windings and causes a failure in these, or possibly even a fire in a worst case scenario.

Driving the turbine from something other than the blades might have an effect. You might find that without the blades, there's less wear on the shaft from other forces, such as less vibration. Particularly if there's play in the shaft, you might reduce wear from that. Of course, if you're coupling doesn't have good concentricity, you might wear something out sooner. If you drive the turbine from a belt, for example, the belt will apply some lateral force to the shaft from its tension, that if not properly supported could weaken/wear it. I presume there's a mechanical engineering SE that you could go to for further input on the mechanical coupling to your turbine.